# Resources path for MVC application in subdirectory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, url-rewriting

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application deployed in azure, lets say myapp.cloudapp.net. And there is also PHP-based information website (lets say www.sample.com). MVC application should be accesible as www.sample.com/myapp - this is achieved with rewriting on load balancer. Now, there is one issue - paths to resources (css, images, scripts) for MVC application are incorrect - they point to the root (www.sample.com), and of course, they are not there.

How to fix this in some clean and supported way? I dont want to create directory "myapp" and move resources there, if there is some helper or any way to make one easily..

Thanx!

Comment: Why don't you use relative paths for your resources?

Comment: You could also write a route that captures requests to their current location and serves them up accordingly. Or if you don't want to use MVC routes you could add a rule to your web.config which provides the same functionality - although the former approach is preferred.